# Assimp not loading names for neither the meshes nor the animations

Tags: c++, c, 3d, models, assimp

I'm using Assimp to load COLLADA models, but the `scene->mMeshes[i]->mName.C_Str()` call returns me `" "` for every existing mesh index (of course, `" "` is not their original name). The same happens for the animations.

However, I can retrieve the name of the bones and the nodes correctly.

I've also tried loading `.ply` and `.obj` models with the same results. Is this a problem of my program or is everyone experiencing the same issue?

PS: I'm using Blender v2.70 to export the models.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the Collada imported that was already fixed: http://sourceforge.net/p/assimp/discussion/817653/thread/e3dccf5a/

Answer (score 0):

Update the collada exporter. That will solve it.